# Express.js : variable stored in `res.locals` isn't defined in the view

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In an express application, i'm using an express router declared in the `app.js` as:

```
var adminRouter = require('./admin');
app.use("/admin", adminRouter);
```

so it references the `admin.js` file in which i defined this specific route :

```
 router.route('/rooms/edit/:id')
    .all(function(req, res, next) {
        var roomid = req.params.id;
        var room = _.find(rooms, r => r.id == roomid);
        if (!room) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
            return;
        }
        res.locals.room = room;
        next();
    }).get(function(req, res) {

        res.render('edit', { room: room });
    }).post(function(req, res) {

        res.locals.room.name = req.body.name;
        res.redirect('./'); 
    });
```

but in the view for editing the room name (accessed by the .get method in the route above) i get this error saying that the `room` variable i stored in `res.locals` isn't defined :

```
ReferenceError: room is not defined
```

here is the whole `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser =  require('body-parser');


app.set("views", "./views");
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('incomming req : ' + req.url);
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {title:'Home'});
});

var adminRouter = require('./admin');
app.use("/admin", adminRouter);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('app running on port 3000');
});
```

and this is the edit.jade view too :

```
extends layout
block content
 h1 Edit chatroom!!
 form(method="POST")
      fieldset.form-group
          label(for="name") Name:
          input.form-control(name="name", type="text", placeholder="Enter a name" value="#{room.name}")
          small.text-muted Give your chatroom a meaningful name for people to refer to it.
      button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Save chatroom
      a.btn.btn-default(href="/admin/rooms") Cancel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get this error saying that the `room` variable i stored in `res.locals` isn't defined :
>
> ```
> ReferenceError: room is not defined
> ```

That's not what the error says: it says that a *variable* called `room` isn't defined. It should have also pointed you to the line of code where the error happens, which is here:

```
res.render('edit', { room: room });
```

Where, in fact, `room` *is* undefined.