# A form with POST method submitting a GET

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

This is the strangest problem i ever had, this is the view (in jade):

```
extends layout
block content
 h1 Edit chatroom!!
 form(method="POST")
      fieldset.form-group
          label(for="name") Name:
          input.form-control(name="name", type="text", placeholder="Enter a name" value="#{room.name}")
          small.text-muted Give your chatroom a meaningful name for people to refer to it.
      button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Save chatroom
      a.btn.btn-default(href="/admin/rooms") Cancel
```

this is the form source from the page source code returned to the browser :

```
<form method="POST">
               <fieldset class="form-group"><label for="name">Name:</label><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a name" value="independents" class="form-control"><small class="text-muted">Give your chatroom a meaningful name for people to refer to it.</small></fieldset>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save chatroom</button><a href="/admin/rooms" class="btn btn-default">Cancel        </a>
            </form>
```

when i press the "Save chatroom" button i get this error message on the web page :

```
Cannot GET /admin/rooms/edit/
```

this express router is supposed to handel the form submission

```
router.route('/rooms/edit/:id')
.all(function(req, res, next) {
    var roomid = req.params.id;
    var room = _.find(rooms, r => r.id == roomid);
    if (!room) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return;
    }
    res.locals.room = room;
    next();
}).get(function(req, res) {
    res.render('edit');
}).post(function(req, res) {
    res.locals.room.name = req.body.name;
    //res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/rooms'); or we can also
    res.redirect('./'); // but this is not good because if we had http://localhost:3000/admin/rooms/add/ it will take us to /add
});
```

the whole code for this small express app(two js files) exist in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839765/express-js-variable-stored-in-res-locals-isnt-defined-in-the-view) i wrote.

Comment: You did a redirect to `res.redirect('./');`, so it follows the redirect and makes a GET request. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route defintion you have

```
if (!room) {
  res.sendStatus(404);
  return;
}
```

And it looks like in your code, you're not submitting any request to a URL that has an ID, so it's returning 404 just like you told it to.

Unless you're on a URL that does have an ID. What does the URL look like on the page this is on?

Comment: the res.redirect('./'); was the problem because i debugged the routes and evrything was fine , now as i changed that redirect to res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/rooms'); it works and i don't know why the problem happened